# Probability question involving Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: probability

No idea how to do this question.

A coin is tossed $n$ times.
Let $A_i=1$ if a head is obtained on the $i$-th toss and $A_i=0$, otherwise.
Let $\bar A_n$ denote the proportion of heads obtained after $n$ tosses.
Use Chebyshev's Inequality to find $n$ so that:
$P[0.4 \leq \bar A_n \leq 0.6] \geq 0.8 $

And also then find $n$ using the known distribution of $\bar A_n$

Comment: You can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations. :) Also, even though you're confused about the right way to approach this problem, could you share any equation manipulations that you've tried?

Comment: Is it a fair coin with $p=0.5$?

Comment: If you don´t give a reply nobody can help you.,

Comment: I was offline, yes it's a fair coin

Comment: Next time you should wait a few minutes to clarify your question before getting offline. Since the question is put on hold I cannot post an answer.

Comment: @samdawson2020 I have a little bit other approach than [BruceET](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221800/bruceet) -but I have got the same result. $\color{red}{\checkmark}$.

Comment: My bad, new to the site and didn't expect answers that fast. I'll know next time

Comment: @samdawson2020 OK, no problem, You´re lucky, you had gotten an answer before the answer has been put on hold. If you have any questions you can leave a comment below the answer. If everything is clear  please mark the anwer as `accepted`.

Comment: Voted to re-open. Pretty clear from context coin has to be fair, otherwise problem is messy. Think we sometimes get impatient and close Questions too quickly. But you gave no clue what you may have tried on your own. [As a practical matter, expts have shown that almost anything that _looks_ like a coin is very nearly fair; but sub-optimal tossing can produce unfair results. Coin must tumble several times.] // I did not intend to _work_ the problem, only to give clues that would help you do it. If anything unclear please leave Comment saying exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it's a fair coin. Then $E(\bar A_n) = 1/2$ and
$Var(\bar A_n) = 1/4n$ so $\sigma = SD(\bar A_n) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$

Then Chebyshev's Inequality amounts to
$$P(1/2 - k\sigma \le \bar A_n \le 1/2 + k\sigma) \ge 1 - 1/k^2.$$

First use $1 - 1/k^2 = 0.8$ to find $k$ (which need not be an integer).
Then use $\sigma = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ to find $n$ such that $k\sigma = 0.1.$

[If it's not a fair coin, make adjustments accordingly.]

Because Chebyshev's Inequality applies to all distributions that meet very general conditions, it usually does not give very precise bounds for any one
specific distribution. So as a practical matter, the $n$ you get will be
unnecessarily large.

Note: If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=40,p=.5)$ then
$P(16 \le X \le 24) = P(.4 \le \bar A_{40} \le .6) = 0.8461.$ [Thirty is not quite big enough.] 
Computations in R statistical software:

```
diff(pbinom(c(15,24), 40, .5))
## 0.8461401                            # exact binomial probability
diff(pnorm(c(15.5,24.5), 20, sqrt(10)))
## 0.8452711                            # normal approx with continuity corr
```